# Removing date and time from Ubuntu lock screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu

This will be just a quick one.
How to remove date and time from the middle of Ubuntu lock screen?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Actually, I am now updating to 18.04